# merge objects having same value as property in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The data is an array, that has some objects in it. the objective here is to merge the objects which have same x and y values.

the code is given below:

```js
let data = [{ "x": 1, "y": 2, "color": "red" }, { "x": 1, "y": 2, "stroke": "violet" }, { "x": 3, "y": 4, "color": "green" }, { "x": 3, "y": 4, "stroke": "blue" }];

var finalArr = data.reduce((m, o) => {
    var found = m.find(p => (p.x === o.x) && (p.y === o.y) );
    if (found) {
        found = {...o}
    } else {
        m.push(o);
    }
    return m;
}, []);
```

the original data array is:

```js
let data = [
{ "x": 1, "y": 2, "color": "red" },
{ "x": 1, "y": 2, "stroke": "violet" },
{ "x": 3, "y": 4, "color": "green" },
{ "x": 3, "y": 4, "stroke": "blue" }
];
```

the expected result is:

```js
let data = [
{ "x": 1, "y": 2, "color": "red", "stroke": "violet" },
{ "x": 3, "y": 4, "color": "green", "stroke": "blue" }
];
```

Comment: And the question/problem is? And what have you done so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I used the reduce method as seen in the code, but not getting the expected results

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object with a joined key and assign the actual object to the object for the group.

```js
const
    data = [{ x: 1, y: 2, color: "red" }, { x: 1, y: 2, stroke: "violet" }, { x: 3, y: 4, color: "green" }, { x: 3, y: 4, stroke: "blue" }],
    getKey = o => [o.x, o.y].join('|'),
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.assign(r[getKey(o)] ??= {}, o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this works but fails in my app: Error "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders" - how could I write this without using the operator ??=

Answer (score 1):

First, accumulate key-value pairs for x and y key pair and finally and x and y as values into the same level.

This would also work.

```js
const data = [
  { x: 1, y: 2, color: "red" },
  { x: 1, y: 2, stroke: "violet" },
  { x: 3, y: 4, color: "green" },
  { x: 3, y: 4, stroke: "blue" },
];

const output = Object.entries(
  data.reduce((prev, { x, y, ...rest }) => {
    if (prev[`${x}-${y}`]) {
      prev[`${x}-${y}`] = { ...prev[`${x}-${y}`], ...rest };
    } else {
      prev[`${x}-${y}`] = { ...rest };
    }
    return prev;
  }, {})
).map(([key, value]) => {
  const [x, y] = key.split("-");
  return { x, y, ...value };
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply do this**

```js
let data = [{ "x": 1, "y": 2, "color": "red" }, { "x": 1, "y": 2, "stroke": "violet" }, { "x": 3, "y": 4, "color": "green" }, { "x": 3, "y": 4, "stroke": "blue" }];


let result = data.reduce((acc, d ) => {
  acc[d.x] ??= {x: d.x, y: d.y };
  acc[d.x].stroke = d.stroke;
  acc[d.x].color = d.color;
 
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```